# When user hits the submit button, index.php does not catch the action and update database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have 3 files here, index.php, authors.html.php and form.html.php, index.php is my controller script that then calls authors.html.php to display the authors and finally form.html.php when a user wants to edit an author or add an author in a MySQL database.

The problem I run into is that when the user hits the update button, the database does not get update the author details... it seems my controller script is not catching the 'editform' action? I'm no entirely sure why it's slipping. Here are excerpts from the files:

index.php (controller):

```
    <?php
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';

    if ((isset($_POST['action'])) and ($_POST['action'] == 'Edit'))
    {
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php'; //connect to mysql
        try
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT id, name, email FROM author WHERE id = :id';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $s->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = 'Error fetching author details...';
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        $row = $s->fetch();

        $pageTitle = 'Edit Author';
        $action = 'editform';
        $name = $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $button = 'Update Author';

        include 'form.html.php';
        header('Location: .');
        exit();
    }

    if (isset($_GET['editform']))
    {
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php'; //connect to mysql

        try
        {
            $sql = 'UPDATE author SET name = :name, email = :email WHERE id = :id';
            $s->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $s->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
            $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
            $s->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = "Error updating selected author.";
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        header('Location: .');
        exit();
    }

    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

    try
    {
        $result = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name FROM author');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $error = 'Error fetching authors from the database: ';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $authors[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name']);
    }
    include 'authors.html.php';
    ?>
```

authors.html.php

```
    <?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/helpers.inc.php' ?>
    // When I call "htmlout()" is the same as "echo htmlspecialchars()"
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Manage Authors</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                <h1>Manage Authors</h1>
                <p>
                    <a href="?add">Add New Author</a>
                </p>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?>
                    <li>
                        <form action="?<?php $action ?>" method="post">
                            <div>
                                <?php htmlout($author['name']); ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $author['id']; ?>">
                                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit">
                                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                   </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <p>
                    <a href="..">Return to JMS Home</a>
                </p>
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

form.html.php

```
   <?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/helpers.inc.php' ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
               <title><?php htmlout($pageTitle); ?></title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h1><?php htmlout($pageTitle); ?></h1>

           <form action="?<?php $action ?>" method="post">
               <div>
                   <label for="name">Name:
                       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php htmlout($name); ?>">
                   </label>
               </div>
               <div>
                   <label for="email">Email:
                       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php htmlout($email); ?>">
                   </label>
               </div>
               <div>
                   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlout($id); ?>">
                   <input type="submit" name="action" value="<?php htmlout($button) ?>">
               </div>
           </form>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: why using GET param for this action and use a POST request?

Comment: I imagine $action is set in your helpers file?  What is it set to?  Also, throw a "var_dump($_POST);die();" at the top of the file you are routing the request to and make sure it's getting there that way you know which file the problem is in.

Comment: $action is set at the top actually, 
 $pageTitle = 'Edit Author'; $action = 'editform'; $name = $row['name']; $email = $row['email']; $id = $row['id']; $button = 'Update Author';

Comment: @linus72982 I will try the var_dump() and update you guys, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I did wrong! Phew...

I screwed up on this line

```
$s->prepare($sql);
```

it should have been

```
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

and as @MamaWalter pointed out, I was looking at $_GET for a $_POST variable, so I changed that it it's now working great!

@linus72982 Your suggestion to use var_dump() was a tremendous help, I am new to PHP and thus did not know about it... thanks again for everything!